# Azure Logic App SFTP (SSH) connector - Enable Proxy Protocol

Tags: azure, ssh, sftp, azure-logic-apps, proxy-protocol

We have an Azure Logic App which connects to an external SFTP server via SSH. A couple of days ago the Logic App connector began to fail due to a "Gateway Timeout":

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 504,
    "source": "logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "********-a74a-4212-93fa-*********",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 504,
      "message": "Request to the SFTP server has taken more than '00:00:30' seconds.\r\nclientRequestId: ********-a74a-4212-93fa-*********",
      "error": {
        "message": "Request to the SFTP server has taken more than '00:00:30' seconds."
      },
      "source": "sftpwithssh-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
  }
}
```

We figured out that the external partner enabled the proxy protocol on their side which is the reason the Azure SFTP SSH connector fails.

**Does the SFTP-SSH connector support proxy protocol and if yes how to configure it?**

Unfortunately I did not found any information in the documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh